# Is it safe to use the Administrator Tasks in Central Administration?

Tags: sharepoint

Strange question, but: Sharepoint 2007 greets you with the Administrator Tasks on the Central Administration after installation.

I just wonder if this list is "safe" to be used for my own Administration Tasks? The reason why i'm asking is because I found that Sharepoint uses a lot of "black magic" and unlogical behaviour and breaks rather easily, so I do not want risk breaking anything if i'm entering my own tasks into the task list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use that list as it seems to be specially modified with various extra fields and I wouldn't want to misuse those.

It may just pay you to create your own administrative tasks list.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. While the list just invites to be used for my own purposes, Sharepoint likes to crash if you even *look* at it the wrong way. I'll continue with using my own Task List.

Answer (score 1):

That list is extensible. You can get a reference to that list via the object model:
   SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.AdministrativeTasks

I understand your concern, but in this case, you are free to add to this list as you wish.